# Customize AWS scheduled event notifications recipients

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a simple way to change or add the recipients of the Instance Retirement notifications?
The owner of the account is getting it but he's not the one who's suppose to take care of it. We would also like to have multiple recipients (and not just the account official owner and the operations back-up).
It seems that aside from adding/removing tags and adding an operations back-up there's no way to change it but it is weird as almost anything else can be controlled in a simple way.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Health events with Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/cloudwatch-events-health.html) to route the events and take actions necessary depending on the use case like as described in the doc you can even automate the workflow needed for specific actions.

> You can use Amazon CloudWatch Events to detect and react to changes for AWS Health events. Then, based on the rules that you create, CloudWatch Events invokes one or more target actions when an event matches the values that you specify in a rule. Depending on the type of event, you can send notifications, capture event information, take corrective action, initiate events, or take other actions. For example, you can use AWS Health to receive email notifications if you have AWS resources in your AWS account that are scheduled for updates, such as Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances.